# Store/Reload CNTK Trainer, Model, Inputs, Outputs

Tags: python, cntk

What is the best way to store a trainer and all necessary components?

**1. Storing:**

- Store checkpoint of the [trainer](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.train.trainer.html): Use its `trainer.save_checkpoint(filename, external_state={})` function
- Additionally store the model separately: Use the `z.save(filename)` method, every cntk operation has. You can also get `z = trainer.model`.

**2. Reloading:**

- Restore the model: Use `C.load_model(...)`. (Don't get confused by the deprecated persist namespace from the Cntk 1.)
- Get the inputs from the restored model.
- Restore the trainer itself: Use `trainer.restore_from_checkpoint` as eg. shown [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/1353). The problem is, this function already needs a trainer object which probably has to be initialized in the same way as the trainer used to create the check point!?

How do I now restore the label-inputs which are going into the error function used by the trainer? In the following code I marked the variables which I think I have to restore after I once stored them.

```
z = C.layers.Dense(.... )
loss = error = C.squared_error(z, **l**)
**trainer** = C.Trainer(**z**, (loss, error), [mylearner], my_tensorboard_writer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore your trainer, but I actually prefer to just load my model `m`. The simple reason is that it is much easier to create a whole new trainer, beacuse then you can change all the other parameters of the trainer more easily.
Then you can get the input variable from the loaded model (if your network has only one input):

```
input_var = m.arguments[0]
```

then you need the output of your model:

```
output = m(input_var)
```

and define the loss function using your target output `target_output`:

```
C.squared_error(output, target_output)
```

using your model and the loss function you can recreate your trainer from there, setting the learning rate etc. as you like